# R - ggplot - Rounded extremity for geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

This is a simple example of what my barplot look like :

```
x <- data.frame(aa=c(0.2,0.6,0.1), dd = c(1,2,3))
x <- melt(x, "dd")
y <- data.frame(bb=c(0.4,0.5), dd = c(1,2))
y <- melt(y, "dd")
z <- data.frame(cc=c(0.5,0.25,0.1,0.05), dd = c(1,2,3,4))
z <- melt(z, "dd")

x=rbind(x,y,z)

col=c("white","grey","blue","white","red","white","green","blue","green")
ggplot(x, aes(x = variable, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = col)
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to have rounded ends for my bars, like with the lineend option for a line (http://sape.inf.usi.ch/quick-reference/ggplot2/lineend) ?

Comment: I doubt that, would like to see if anyone knows solution to this problem.

Comment: In barplot you need to compare the heights of different bars. so, the edge needs to be as straight as possible. Aesthetics is not the only thing to consider. purpose of plotting is different.

Comment: Why would you need this? Are you trying to make them look like 3D pipes?

Comment: It's not really important. My bars are chromosomes, and usually chromosome's mosaics have rounded extremities ;)

Comment: Use [ggbio package](http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/ggbio.html), `Ideogram` function

Comment: Or here here is a starting point: `ggplot(x, aes(x=variable, y=value)) +  geom_path(size=10, lineend="round",col=col)`

Comment: Thanks zx8754 !
It did the trick !

Comment: @JustinB if you figured out how to use `geom_path()` to make the rounded corners, do you mind posting an answer? I'm curious to see how it came out.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example where the bars have rounded ends, used with **geom_line** (geom_path), serving as a minimal example.

```
df1 <- data.frame( x=c(1,1,2,2,3,3),
                   y=c(1,7,1,4,1,5),
                   chr=c("one","one","two","two","three","three") )

ggplot( df1, aes(x,y, col=chr) ) + geom_line( lineend="round", lwd=10 )
```

[image: ggplot_geom_line]